# Which real life materials are emulated using the facing output of the layer weight node in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

### Scenario:

Imagine you use **Cycles** and you are in the **node editor**. You use a **mix shader** and connect two other nodes into its color input, for instance two **glossy shader** with different colors. Now you take the output of the **layer weight node** and put it into the **fac** input of the **mix shader**.

### Result:

The result is, that which of the two shaders dominates depends on the angle from which  you look onto the object. If the **normal** of one of the **faces** of your object is **parallel** to your viewing direction the upper shader is at 100 % dominance and the wider the angle between this normal and your viewing direction gets, the more the lower shader's influence rises.

### Real life occurence:

This looks strange to me in the sense, that I am not used to materials with such optical properties in the real world, I do not even know if I have ever seen such a material knowingly. However, I would like to know if there are  typical objects in the real life which behave in such way, so I could try to emulate them in Blender.

Comment: you cannot expect real life to be able to replicate cycles' nodes possibilities, the tool is thought the other way around... in blender you can design all sort of (fake) crazyness, eg: materials changing colors in sync with a dance music track (https://www.blendernation.com/2017/06/30/tutorial-control-everything-music-blender/) but you can't expect that to be doable in real life (yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materials that are [iridescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescence) will be like that. A CD or DVD would be an example.

Fancy car paint will do those effects in the real world: depending on the angle you look at the object they could have different color.

An example of such materials used in architecture can be found here: https://www.azahner.com/works/team-disney